# How To Connect my android Application To Internet Automatically whenever network found

Tags: android

My android application is based on network connection i.e WIFI/Mobile Network. It works fine when my mobile is connected to internet but when internet connection disconnected it stops working (obesely) and it still stop working after my mobile again connected to internet.

**I wish to (re)start my application automatically whenever internet connection is (re)established.**

Comment: Are u sure u would be checking for internet all the time...? 

Doesn't this makes your app resource intensive...??

Comment: use broadcast receiver for the same

Answer (score 3):

You can check the network state using broadcast receiver. Whenever the network is available, you can start your application.

First, create a background service and start your service when the device boots up. Now, in this service, register a broadcast receiver and monitor the network state. If the network is available, you can start your application; and if unavailable, you can close it.

Please refer to the code below for broadcast receiver.

```
public class BroadCastSampleActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.registerReceiver(this.mConnReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
            String reason = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
            boolean isFailover = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);

            NetworkInfo currentNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            NetworkInfo otherNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_OTHER_NETWORK_INFO);

            if(currentNetworkInfo.isConnected())
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must need to checking continue for network connections, that means you need to check for internet connection in background tasks. Android Services is better option for that, create one Service and start it when your app starts, inside that just do one code and that is for checking Internet Connectivity, when it lost, do some task and when it found you can do whatever you want. So I suggest you to use services and get your task done.

Here are some links to refer.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a spread **thread**  or **service** in background for checking  network connection after some interval . use following code in thread or service whatever you want to create .

```
NetworkInfo i = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
  if (i == null)
    return false;
  if (!i.isConnected())
    return false;
  if (!i.isAvailable())
    return false;
  return true;
```