# Is there a way to start my android app whenever internet is avaliable(wifi/mobile)?

Tags: android

I'm new to android. I know that I can start my app on boot using `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`

But what I want is if my app was closed after boot,it will start automatically at least twice a day,would be better if it starts whenever internet is available (supposing my app closes and user doesn't reboot).

I cant use a persistent service,because I don't want to use that much resource.

And I don't want to use root or Accessibility service.

OK, I did some more search and found that it can be done using a background service.
But is there any better way to do it?

Comment: use `WIFI_STATE_CHANGED` and `STATE_CHANGE` receiver check this [post](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-internet-connection-status-network-change/)

Comment: thanks mohit. But does this mean after creating Broadcast Receiver if my app is closed it will start whenever CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE happens?

Comment: on connectivity changed check if internet is available or not and start your app..

Comment: If my app is killed,it's broadcast receiver is not running. What I asked was in this case how can I " tell " the system to launch my app by its main activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start your activity in onRecieve method like this:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);
 context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I'm really confused on this. If my app is not running, how can it's  onRecieve method run?

Comment: I read this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27915192/how-to-connect-my-android-application-to-internet-automatically-whenever-network) I want to know can I do it without using a background service.